# How to apply a mapper to a specific portion of a column of a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, imputation

Basically I am trying to impute some values in a column based on some values in another column. So I am going through the records, where `customer` is missing, and then trying to impute `SALES_LOCATION` for those specific records.

So, I tried:

```
customer_to_sales_location_mapper = dict()
for customer in transaction_data[pd.isnull(transaction_data.SALES_LOCATION)].CUSTOMER:
  count_dict = dict(transaction_data[transaction_data.CUSTOMER == customer]['SALES_LOCATION'].value_counts())
  if count_dict:
    sales_location = sorted(((key, val) for key, val in count_dict.items()), key=lambda x: -x[1])[0][0]
  else:
    sales_location = 'Zürich East'
  customer_to_sales_location_mapper[customer] = sales_location

print(customer_to_sales_location_mapper)
```

Now, I have a mapping like:

```
{'123': 'Zurich', '345': 'Luzane', ......}
```

Now I want to change the `SALES_LOCATION` of `transaction_data[pd.isnull(transaction_data.SALES_LOCATION)]` based on `CUSTOMER` values.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your pandas operations, they are quite inefficient because you are filtering your entire dataset in each loop. Here's a more efficient version:

```
customer_to_sales_location_mapper = dict()
null_locations = pd.isnull(transaction_data.SALES_LOCATION)
for tup in transaction_data[null_locations].itertuples():
  count_dict = dict(tup.SALES_LOCATION.value_counts())
  if count_dict:
    sales_location = sorted(((key, val) for key, val in count_dict.items()), key=lambda x: -x[1])[0][0]
  else:
    sales_location = 'Zürich East'
  customer_to_sales_location_mapper[tup.CUSTOMER] = sales_location
```

Now to answer your question:

```
# We can reuse `null_locations`
transaction_data[null_locations, "CUSTOMER"] = transaction_data.loc[null_locations].apply(
    lambda x: customer_to_sales_location_mapper[x["CUSTOMER"]], axis=1)
```

I haven't tested this because I don't have your data.